# Objective C: How to change text color in navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, icons, uinavigationbar, textcolor

I have changed my navigation bar color via the following code

```
navconFvc.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"faf6f5"];
```

The code worked but the text color also needs to be changed (see screenshot below). Also the refresh button logo on the right is affected as well

[image]

The same issue occurs if I navigate to another page in the stack

[image]

Question: How can I change the color of the

- title text
- Back button text and
- right bar button icon color?

After I changed the background color of the navbar?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the title here's the way:

[iPhone Navigation Bar Title text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599405/iphone-navigation-bar-title-text-color)

And for the custom buttons here's the way:

[adding buttons to ui navigation controller bottom bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087285/adding-buttons-to-ui-navigation-controller-bottom-bar)

Comment: Rincon-Fadul, thanks for the links, the first link works well for me. However, I am still not sure how I can change the button's text color or icon color. For icon, I probably can change the image directly. But what about the back button text color for instance? The link doesn't really explain about that part

Comment: Old answer, use @Erwan's one

Answer (score 18):

In iOS 7, just use:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
```

Change [UIColor whiteColor] with whatever text color you want

Answer (score 7):

To change text color:

```
_navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes 
         = @{UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor blackColor]};
```

Adding refresh button and color it:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
         initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
         target:self action:@selector(reload)];

[button setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
```

Variables that effect navigation bar background:

```
_navController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just put together a simple `UIViewController` subclass that adds a customizable back button that allows you to change text colors. It basically adds some `willAppear`/`willDisappear` logic to animate the back button the way the `UINavigationController` does while using the `leftBarButtonItem` property. You might extend this to also do the rightBarButtomItem as well.

https://github.com/typeoneerror/BBCustomBackButtonViewController