# NavigationController color and left button

Tags: c#, ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

I am trying out making my first table based app.. However it wont change the color of the title on the navbar.

I tried this code, but it does not seem to work:

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationItem.TitleView.TintColor = UIColor.White;
```

Also I made a LeftBarButtonItem, however I can't see it, but when clicked where it should be, it does do what it should..

```
    this.NavigationController.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton (true, false);
    this.NavigationController.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem ();
    this.NavigationController.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem.Style = UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain;
    this.NavigationController.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem.TintColor = UIColor.White;
    this.NavigationController.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem.Title = "Tilbage";
    this.NavigationController.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
    {
        this.PerformSegue("fromItem", this);
    };
```

Comment: Is this objective-c ???

Comment: Nope, it's c#.. Made in Xamarin/MonoTouch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the color of the title in navigation bar check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/621185/1441667).

And for the custom buttons in the navigation bar check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5610694/1441667)

If you have any problems translating objective-c to C#, write a comment.

**EDIT**

In `ViewDidLoad` of your `ViewController` add:

```
// to change the appearance of the top navigation bar title
UITextAttributes attributes = new UITextAttributes();
    // set custom text color
attributes.TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255, 122, 122);
attributes.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(20);
attributes.TextShadowColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(255, 255, 255, 128);
attributes.TextShadowOffset = new UIOffset(2, -2);

// to add buttons to navigation bar
UIBarButtonItem[] items = new UIBarButtonItem[]
{
    new UIBarButtonItem(
        NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("Tilbage", null),
        UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered,
        delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            // do whatever you need
        Console.WriteLine("Custom button clicked!");
    })
};

NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(255, 196, 196, 255);
NavigationController.NavigationBar.TopItem.Title = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("LocalizedHeader", null);
// change appearance
NavigationController.NavigationBar.SetTitleTextAttributes(attributes);
// add buttons
NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItems = items;
```

Answer (score 0):

The properties you are looking for are probably:

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor;
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor; //this one is iOS7 only
```

Comment: I've changed the color of the bar itself, however I am looking to change the text color of the title(ie. News), and also I added a left button instead of the back button, but it does not show up.